# How to Access Online judge on Internet?

Tags: amazon-web-services, ubuntu, networking, amazon-ec2

I want to implement a Online judge for my college's Coding Club.
There is an online Judge named '[mooshak](http://mooshak.dcc.fc.up.pt)'. I have installed it on my Amazon Web Services Ubuntu 12.04. It is accessible only via localhost. But I want to make it access on internet so that whole college student can use it. How can I do that? 
**I am a complete beginner in networking related stuffs.**

Answer (score 1):

The application needs to listen on a public IP address, and you need to configure the EC2 instance's [security group](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/GettingStartedGuide/getting-started-create-security-group.html) such that the application's port is open to either the world or just a subset of IP addresses owned by your college.